# tf.round() to a specified precision

Tags: tensorflow, floating-point, rounding, precision

[`tf.round(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/round) rounds the values of `x` to integer values.

Is there any way to round to, say, 3 decimal places instead?

Answer (score 11):

You can do it easily like that, if you don't risk reaching too high numbers:

```py
def my_tf_round(x, decimals = 0):
    multiplier = tf.constant(10**decimals, dtype=x.dtype)
    return tf.round(x * multiplier) / multiplier
```

Mention: The value of x * multiplier should not exceed 2^32. So using the above method, should not rounds too high numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution of gdelab is very Good moving the required decimal point numbers to left for "." then get them later like "0.78969 * 100" will move 78.969 "2 numbers" then Tensorflow round will make it 78 then you divide it by 100 again making it 0.78 it smart one There is another workaround I would like to share for the Community.

**You Can just use the NumPy round method by taking the NumPy matrix or vector then applying the method then convert the result to tensor again**

```
#Creating Tensor
x=tf.random.normal((3,3),mean=0,stddev=1)
x=tf.cast(x,tf.float64)
x



#Grabing the Numpy array from tensor
x.numpy()


#use the numpy round method then convert the result to tensor again
value=np.round(x.numpy(),3)
Result=tf.convert_to_tensor(temp,dtype=tf.float64)
Result
```