# Why does Tensorflow output these simple results?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm brand new to Tensorflow, but I'm trying to figure out why these results end in `...001`, `...002`, etc.

I'm following the tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

**Code:**

```
"""This is a Tensorflow learning script."""
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W*x + b

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #This is the same as the above 2 lines

print(sess.run(linear_model, {x: [1, 2, 3, 4]}))
```

It looks like a simple math function where if I was using 2 as an input, it would be `(0.3 * 2) + -0.3 = 0.3`.

**Output:**

> [ 0.          0.30000001  0.60000002  0.90000004]

I would expect:

> [ 0.          0.3  0.6  0.9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a floating point error, because you introduced your variables as a tf.float32 dtype. You could use tf.round (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/round) but it doesn't seem to have round-to-the-nearest decimal place capability yet. For that, check out the response in: [tf.round() to a specified precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688610/tf-round-to-a-specified-precision).

Comment: I've added the function and added a line `linear_model = my_tf_round(linear_model, 1)` and it has affected the results, but they're now `[ 0.          0.30000001  0.60000002  0.89999998]`. Not quite sure what's going on...I'd think they'd make a better example to start with.

Comment: For your particular example, you could simply replace the line `linear_model = W*x + b` with `linear_model = tf.cast(10*(W*x + b), tf.int32)/10`. I just tried running your code with that replacement, and it gave me the output `[ 0.   0.3  0.6  0.9]`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a [floating point variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) (like tf.float32) simply cannot store **exactly** `0.3` due to being stored in binary.  It's like trying to store **exactly** `1/3` in decimal, it'd be `0.33...` but you'd have to go out to infinity to get the exact number (which isn't possible our mortal realm!).

See [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for more in depth review of the subject.

Tensorflow doesn't have a way to deal with decimal numbers yet (as far as I know)! But once the numbers are returned to python you could round & then convert to a [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: I know binary well enough to convert from decimal but I didn't even think about storing floats...great info.

Comment: Tom Scott actually has [a fantastic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) on the subject, (where I learned about this).  Or while googling I found a [great stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100502/7607701) on the topic.  But the tl;dr is that floats are kinda like scientific notation in binary, they are actually two binary numbers X & Y where the number is: X + 2^Y.